# Insert into DataTable from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable, enumerable

I want to insert data from one DataTable to another with some conditions. I have found this link useful: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/7a5d0f88-3e71-435a-ae3c-ff01d1ca22a2/ but I'm not able to put `.ToList()` for my query. I'm getting the below error:

`'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Could some please help me to resolve this?

PS: My query:

```
(from crow in dtConfiguration.AsEnumerable()
                         where crow.Field<string>("FieldType") == "FL"
                         & crow.Field<string>("FieldName") != "DATEADDED"
                         & crow.Field<string>("FieldName") != "DATEMODIFIED"
                         select crow).ToList()
```

Comment: do you have `using System.Linq;` ?

Comment: You may have to use System.Linq namespace ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following statement to your code:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you would need a reference to System.Data.DataSetExtensions commenly found at
C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean!!! I asked this Question 3 months ago & it is already resolved.